# Synchronous API wrapper over asynchronous callback-based API

Tags: go, asynchronous, design-patterns

I'm using the [pion/webrtc](https://github.com/pion/webrtc) Go library in my project and found this problem that the callback-based API the library provides (which mirrors the JavaScript API of WebRTC) can be awkward to use in Go.

For example, doing the following

```
conn.OnTrack(func(...) { ... })
conn.OnICEConnectionStateChange(func(...) { ... })
```

is typical in JavaScript, but in Go, this has a few problems:

- This API makes it easy to introduce data race, if the callbacks are called in parallel.
- The callback-based API propagates to other part of the codebase and makes everything takes callbacks.

What's the conventional way to handle this situation in Go? I'm new to Go and I read that synchronous API is preferred in Go because Goroutines are cheap. So perhaps one possible design is to use a channel to synchronize the callbacks:

```
msgChan := make(chan Msg)
// or use a separate channel for each type of event?

conn.OnTrack(func(...) {
  msgChan <- onTrackMsg
})
conn.OnICEConnectionStateChange(func(...) {
  msgChan <- onStateChangeMsg
})

for {
  msg := <-msgChan
  // do something depending on the type of msg
}
```

I think forcing synchronization with channels basically mimics the single-threaded nature of JavaScript.

Anyway, how do people usually model event-driven workflow in Go?

Comment: Callbacks are almost never idiomatic in Go; in fact, practically no JavaScript tropes, particularly relating to asynchronous code, are at all valid in Go. Have you taken the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/)? It covers the basics of concurrency which you can extend to cover most situations.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I've taken the tour and the reason you said is exactly why I'm asking this question. I'm trying to add an idiomatic Go wrapper API over a callback-based API ported verbatim from JS.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a channel. Just wrap your async/callback code in a single function that waits for a response, and use a WaitGroup (you could use a channel here instead, but a WaitGroup is much easier):

```
func DoSomething() (someType, error) {
    var result SomeType
    var err error
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    StartAsyncProcess(func() {
        // This is the call back that gets called eventually
        defer wg.Done()
        result = /* Set the result */
        err = /* and/or set the error */
    })
    wg.Wait() // Wait until the callback is called, and exits
    return result, err  // And finally return our values
}
```

You may need/wish to add additional locks or synchronization in the callback, if necessary in your case, if your callback relies on or modifies shared state.

Comment: If I have multiple `StartAsyncProcess` that does different things (as in my demo code), is wait group still appropriate? I feel in this case channel is more convenient.

Comment: Without seeing your example, it's hard to be sure. But a WaitGroup is almost always easier than a channel if the point is to, well... wait... for a group of things.

Comment: I think my question is asking slightly different things. I understand how to synchronize the results of async processes; my question is how to convert an event-driven callback-based JavaScript API to idiomatic Go.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was what I was answering. This is certainly the pattern I've used when writing GopherJS bindings for JS libraries, with great success.